# how do I resolve Zillow API Account not authorized Error?

Tags: python, api, zillow

I am getting this error when I try to use the zillow API

```
from pyzillow.pyzillow import ZillowWrapper, GetDeepSearchResults
API_KEY = 'mykey'
zillow_data = ZillowWrapper(API_KEY)
address = '2114 Bigelow Ave'
zipcode = '98109'
rentzestimate = True
deep_search_response = zillow_data.get_deep_search_results(address,
                                                               zipcode,
                                                               rentzestimate)
result = GetDeepSearchResults(deep_search_response)
```

I get **Status 6: This account is not authorized to execute this API call.**

I've looked at my zillow account and have the APIs checked off, so I should have access to use the API already. I've also waited for several hours after I checked off the APIs on the zillow settings page. Anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: If this helps https://github.com/hanneshapke/pyzillow/issues/9

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to confirm you are actually able to edit the options in API settings. According to this post it looks like zillow does not allow people to do that.

https://github.com/hanneshapke/pyzillow/issues/22