# how I resolve Zillow API Account not authorized Error?

Tags: zillow

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[request] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)

```
        [citystatezip] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

    )

[message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [text] => Error: this account is not authorized to execute this API call
        [code] => 6
    )
```

)

Comment: this is just the output. do you have any code to post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I resolve Zillow API Account not authorized Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313726/how-do-i-resolve-zillow-api-account-not-authorized-error)